# Serving static content alongisde Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I want to server some static content on the root of my web server (landing page) alongside an angular app. I want to be able to serve the static content when the user accesses the '/' (root) of the page while service the app at '/portal'.

I've tried making the static content individual components, but since I'm working with a predefined template I cannot include them (I get parse errors at compile-time, because of duplicate `<doctype>`, etc etc).

Also, I'm serving the whole thing with express, so what I thought of was to make use of express' utilities

```
app.use('/',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/landing')));
app.use('/portal',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
```

so far I got the landing page working, and I'm able to access the prtal part but I see on the console that the resources (vendor.js, runtime.js etc) are not being loaded (404s).

Other combinations of app.use and app.get might get me to the point of accessing the portal and have it working but whenever I refresh the page inside it (I'm logged in) I get a blan page (404).

I have the `<base>` set to `href='/'` but changing it has only complicated things more.

I'm sorry to be asking this, but I'm a complete newbie on angular/express. Is there a way to get around this? I haven't been able to find an example that covers serving static files and an app using express

Would someone please guide me through this? I tried every combination of `app.use` and `app.get` and read lots of documentation without getting a clear understanding of how this would work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

two things in Angular app should be enough:

```
<base href="/portal/">
```

in `index.html`

and
    providers:[
        ...
        {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/portal'},
    ]

in `app.module`

*Edited*: for development mode (port 4200 webpack server) use proxy configuration:

```
"/portal/*.js": {
"target": "http://localhost:4200/",
"secure": false,
"pathRewrite": {
    "^/portal": ""
  }
},

"/portal/*.css": {
"target": "http://localhost:4200/",
"secure": false,
"pathRewrite": {
   "^/portal": ""
  }
},

"/portal/favicon.ico": {
"target": "http://localhost:4200/",
"secure": false,
"pathRewrite": {
   "^/portal": ""
 }
```

},

```
"/portal/assets": {
"target": "http://localhost:4200/",
"secure": false,
"pathRewrite": {
  "^/portal": ""
}
```

}

for "production", whatever backend you use, should be simply configured to point /portal/... to static directory where your app has been built.

Comment: I had tried that already, but my assets weren't loading. I thought of using  --deploy-url=/portal and everything loads ok (seen in the browser console) but the application does not get bootstrapped :-(